# Detecting cycles in an oriented dependency graph and detecting if a vertex is part of the cycle or just depending on one

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph-algorithm

Given an oriented graph, I need a way to detect cycles in the graph, as well as find if a vertex is in a cycle, or just has an edge to one of the vertices in a cycle.

Here's an example:

```
A -> B
B -> A
C -> A
```

The `A -> B` and `B -> A` form a cycle in this case, and should be colored in one way, but the vertex `C` isn't part of the cycle, it just has an edge into the cycle, so it should be colored in a different way.

I can easily detect the cycles themself, by just starting at a random vertex, coloring it, and then doing DFS. If I hit a vertex with the same color, I know I'm in a cycle and will recursively propagate the error back. The problem is that it doesn't allow me to see if the error I got from a recursive call is because I'm currently in a cycle, or because I'm just pointing at one that was previously detected.

The graph basically represents dependencies of lazily evaluated cells, where I'm trying to see if a cell failed to evaluated because it transitively references itself, or because it depends on some other cell which is in a cycle (those two should be different errors.)

The way I have it implemented right now, I simply force evaluation on all the dependencies of a current cell, and assign the value based on the result of that evaluation. But as mentioned previously, this recursion doesn't allow me to distinguish the two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tarjan algorithm for searching strongly connected components of a directed graph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm allows you to make the distinction you need.